# How to fix the nested tree?

Tags: angular, angular7

I am trying to use matnested tree in Angular 7, but I am just getting this:

> 'Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation' error.

I don't understand what this error means and how can I fix it. I have imported all the necessary commands app.module.ts.
Is there any special npm that I should install?

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {FlatTreeControl} from '@angular/cdk/tree';
import {MatTreeFlatDataSource, MatTreeFlattener} from '@angular/material/tree';
import {NestedTreeControl} from '@angular/cdk/tree';
import {MatTreeNestedDataSource} from '@angular/material/tree';
import {BehaviorSubject, Observable, of as observableOf} from 'rxjs';

interface FoodNode {
  name: string;
  children?: FoodNode[];
}

const TREE_DATA: FoodNode[] = [
  {
    name: 'Fruit',
    children: [
      {name: 'Apple'},
      {name: 'Banana'},
      {name: 'Fruit loops'},
    ]
  }, {
    name: 'Vegetables',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Green',
        children: [
          {name: 'Broccoli'},
          {name: 'Brussel sprouts'},
        ]
      }, {
        name: 'Orange',
        children: [
          {name: 'Pumpkins'},
          {name: 'Carrots'},
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
];
@Component({
  selector: 'app-input-screen',
  templateUrl: './input-screen.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-screen.component.scss']

})

export class TreeNestedOverviewExample {
  treeControl = new NestedTreeControl<FoodNode>(node => node.children);
  dataSource = new MatTreeNestedDataSource<FoodNode>();

  constructor() {
    this.dataSource.data = TREE_DATA;
  }

  hasChild = (_: number, node: FoodNode) => !!node.children && node.children.length > 0;
}
export class InputScreenComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

```html
<mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl" class="example-tree">
      <!-- This is the tree node template for leaf nodes -->
      <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodeToggle>
        <li class="mat-tree-node">
          <!-- use a disabled button to provide padding for tree leaf -->
          <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
          {{node.name}}
        </li>
      </mat-tree-node>
      <!-- This is the tree node template for expandable nodes -->
      <mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild">
        <li>
          <div class="mat-tree-node">
            <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle
                    [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.name">
              <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
                {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
              </mat-icon>
            </button>
            {{node.name}}
          </div>
          <ul [class.example-tree-invisible]="!treeControl.isExpanded(node)">
            <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet></ng-container>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </mat-nested-tree-node>
    </mat-tree>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Cause

The `InputScreenComponent` class should be decorated as component, but you decorate `TreeNestedOverviewExample` instead.

## Solution

I would suggest you to move

```
export class TreeNestedOverviewExample {
  treeControl = new NestedTreeControl<FoodNode>(node => node.children);
  dataSource = new MatTreeNestedDataSource<FoodNode>();

  constructor() {
    this.dataSource.data = TREE_DATA;
  }

  hasChild = (_: number, node: FoodNode) => !!node.children && node.children.length > 0;


}
```

before

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-input-screen',
  templateUrl: './input-screen.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-screen.component.scss']

})
```